# Error when printing out to a file with modulo operator - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

With the following script I am reading a table from `file.dat` where I need only the first two columns to be printed out in a new file `stable.txt`

```
finp    = 'file.dat'
fh      = open(finp)
out     = 'stable.txt'
fo      = open(out,'wt')

# Here I skip the header lines
for i in range(7):
    fh.readline()

fo.write = ('x  f(x)\n')
for line in fh:        
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split()
    try:
        x = float(line[0])
        y = float(line[1])
    except:
        continue
    print(x)
    print(type(x))
    fo.write('%20f'%(x))

fh.close()
fo.close()
```

gives back this error

```
0.01
<class 'float'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Mypath\data.py", line 20, in <module>
    fo.write('%20f'%(x))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

but I don't understand why. As you can see x is correctly a float number, then where is the problem?
It is worth noting also that the first line written with `fo.write = ('x  f(x)\n')` is not printed to the .txt output file

Comment: Here you are assigning a string to the write method `fo.write = ('x  f(x)\n')`. You need to use `fo.write('x  f(x)\n')`

Comment: `fo.write = ('x  f(x)\n')` should be `fo.write('x  f(x)\n')` and `fo.write('%20f'%(x))` should be `fo.write('%.20f' % x)`, you are missing the dot.

Comment: Ahhhhh thank you! At first I wanted to create the string and then print it with .write(), but then I changed my mind without correcting it properly. Thank you a lot guys as I would have never spotted it.